# Error 415 while trying to @POST image with MULTIPART_FORM_DATA (Retrofit)

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I have an android project in which I'm sending an image to my Intellij server just to save it in a folder. This is the following code in Android:

**EscanerFragment.java**

```
upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                File file = imgToFile(img);
                RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part myPic = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imagen", file.getName(), requestFile);

                Single.fromCallable(() -> daoParte.subirScan(myPic))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(subirScan -> {
                            subirScan.peek(subido -> {
                                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "subirScan:success");
                            }).peekLeft(error -> {
                                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "subirScan:failure");
                                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, error.getMessage());
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Error al subir el parte escaneado",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            });
                        });
            }
        });
```

That code snippet runs when I click on a certain button. This next one is the code for the file writting of that ImageView:

```
private File imgToFile(ImageView img) {
        BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();
        try {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures");
            dir.mkdirs();
            String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
            File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            return outFile;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And these next ones are the DAO and API calls:

**DaoParte.java**

```
public Either<ApiError, Boolean> subirScan(MultipartBody.Part img) {
        try {
            Call<Boolean> call = parteAPI.subirScan(img);
            Response<Boolean> response = call.execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    return Either.right(response.body());
                } else {
                    return Either.left(ApiError.builder().message("Error al enviar el documento escaneado").fecha(LocalDateTime.now()).build());
                }
            } else {
                return Either.left(ApiError.builder().message("Error de comunicacion").fecha(LocalDateTime.now()).build());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            return Either.left(ApiError.builder().message("Error de comunicacion").fecha(LocalDateTime.now()).build());
        }
    }
```

**ParteAPI**

```
@Multipart
    @POST("api/partes/subirScan")
    Call<Boolean> subirScan(@Part MultipartBody.Part img);
```

When I try to retrieve my image in the server I get error 415 or this error

```
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public java.lang.Boolean EE.rest.RestPartes.subirScan(org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[application/json], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class EE.rest.RestPartes, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@27b9fb3c]}, definitionMethod=public java.lang.Boolean EE.rest.RestPartes.subirScan(org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition), parameters=[Parameter [type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, source=image, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.Boolean}, nameBindings=[]}']. Please see server.log for more details."
```

**RestPartes.java**

```
package EE.rest;

import dao.modelo.Parte;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import servicios.ServiciosPartes;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.List;

@Path("partes")
public class RestPartes {

    private ServiciosPartes sp = new ServiciosPartes();

    @POST
    @Path("/sancionar")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Parte sancionar(@Body String[] datos, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        return sp.sancionar(datos);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getAll")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Parte> getPartes() {
        return sp.getPartes();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/subirScan")
    @Headers("Content-Type:multipart/form-data")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void subirScan(FormDataMultiPart multiPart) {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
}
```

What can I do? I've basically tried everything I've seen.

*Disclaimer*: this is my first question, let me know if you need more details about my problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that the server doesn't know what to do with the response type `Boolean`. Is the Boolean used to signify if the upload was successful? You don't need to return anything other than HTTP Status Code 201 then imo. (so you can also drop `Produces(...)`) or you return the location of the image.

Comment: @thinkgruen thanks for answering! The boolean is exactly for that, just to check if the upload was successful. What should I write instead then? I dont understand it completely

Comment: okay, sorry. let's start with the easiest case: you can also put `void` as a return type (returns nothing). Alternatively, you can return `String` (maybe even `File`) and then use the File from `imgToFile` to get the location. I assume if you do just that, the HTTP Status will be 200, not 201. But this a different topic and for now, I would say it's optional. A status 200 already says "Everything went fine", so boolean isn't required.

Comment: @thinkgruen The problem is that after your first comment, the very first thing i tried was returning `void` but it didn't work as same error occurs: `[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public void EE.rest.RestPartes...` I'm starting to think that this is due to the org.glassfish.jersey.media dependency but I dont know how to configurate it if thats the case.

Comment: Did you have the `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` then already or did you add it afterwards? If anything else fails, you should be good to set the return type to `Response`

Comment: @thinkgruen I tried it with and without the `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` in that method. Could it be that I have `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` and 
`@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` on the class level? I tried moving those annotations to the methods instead too. I'm going to edit my initial post so you can see RestPartes.java completely.

Comment: Ah, yes, in this case removing it doesn't make a difference, because it will be taken from the class level. You can only override class annotations, but not nullify them by leaving them out. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipzh/index.html

Comment: @thinkgruen I read that link but I still cannot figure it out. I've even tried with only class level annotations this way `@Produces({"multipart/form-data", "application/json"})
@Consumes({"multipart/form-data", "application/json"})` but I get the same error anyway. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: I think in your case, you can first try to remove it from the class level. Alternatively, you can return a `Response` object as mentioned in a previous comment. Btw. please be aware that if you put multiple response types, the first applicable one will be chosen. So if the response can be `multipart/form-data`, it will be returned as such.

Comment: @thinkgruen Sadly I can't find the real issue, i removed that jersey media dependency and now the only problem its the initial 415 error, but no more injection error. I've tried removing the annotations from the class level too but nothing seems to work.